# Style event setter can't find what is wrong

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my style part:

```
<Style x:Key="anan" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="/Fonts/#Minecraft"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF19198B"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10 8"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewTextInput" Handler="Left_TextBoxs_previewtextinput"/>
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="Left_TextBoxs_get_GotFocus"/>
        <EventSetter Event="GotMouseCapture" Handler="current_x_get_GotMouseCapture"/>
        <EventSetter Event="IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged" Handler="current_x_get_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF66B616"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The part giving me trouble I couldn't find why it says that **The event is not a rooted event**.

```
<EventSetter Event="IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged" Handler="current_x_get_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged"/>
```

... and here is the xaml.cs

```
private void Left_TextBoxs_get_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.CaptureMouse();
    textBox.SelectAll();
    textBox.Focus();
}

private void current_x_get_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.SelectAll();
}

private void current_x_get_IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Can someone say what is wrong with it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ismousecapturewithinchanged?view=netcore-3.1

As the error message informs you, `IsMouseCaptureWithinChanged` isn't a routed event, but a CLR event. The documentation clearly explains this.

The only way to react to this event is by attaching an event handler to the necessary UI elements.